# How to set linker flags with conan 2.0 with correct escaping

Tags: c++, macos, conan-2

I'm using [conan 2.0](https://docs.conan.io/2/index.html) to create a recipe to publish a Apple Framework written in C++.
Everything is working and the information I need to provided in [package_info](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/conanfile/methods/package_info.html) for the consumer of the Apple Framework is as expected.

Only problem I have is with wrong escaping of the linker flags, which results in a linker warning

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F"/path/to/Frameworks/Generic.framework"'

In the `conanfile.py` in `def package_info(self)` I'm setting the linker flags in this way

```
def package_info(self):
    ...
    framework_location = f'-F"{self.package_folder}/Frameworks/Generic.framework"'

    self.cpp_info.sharedlinkflags.extend([framework_locations)]
    self.cpp_info.exelinkflags = self.cpp_info.sharedlinkflags
```

How do I correctly set the linker flags?
Could it be a bug with conan 2.0?

Comment: you have closing `)` and `]` mixed up on this line `self.cpp_info.sharedlinkflags.extend([framework_locations)]`, perhaps that is the problem?